# Booking Reference Number

Tags: qatar-airways

I have received my itinerary with my booking ref number. I checked with the airline website and it matches what is in our booking ref number. Is this considered a confirmed ticket? Me and my son is travelling together. We have the same Booking ref number.

Comment: Where and how did you book the ticket? If the ref number shows up on the Qatar's website, you should be fine. I recommend making an online account with Qatar and adding the ref number to your account, so it's easy to track any changes, check in, grab seats, etc.

Comment: Everybody with the booking reference number could cancel the flight (and ask for refund). So it is never a definitive "confirmation" (but if you booked on a reliable place, and you have decent computer security, it should not be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

A booking reference is not the same as a ticket.  It's common for agents (either at a travel agency or at an airline) to create a booking and send email with the booking details (including the reference number) to the person arranging the booking in order to verify that everything is correct before purchasing the ticket.

One a booking has been ticketed, most airlines or agents will send email with the booking, including the ticket number, to the person arranging the booking.

If you and your son are the two passengers in the booking, then once ticketed you should see two (or more) ticket numbers in email or in the booking when viewed online.